# Understanding a theorem about fixed-point-free automorphisms

Tags: group-theory

D.J.S. Robinson, A Course in the Theory of Groups, 2d edition, 10.5.3., p. 305-306, states and proves :

> Let $H$ be a group of automorphisms of a finite abelian group $A$. Suppose that $H$ is the semidirect product $\langle \sigma\rangle\ltimes M$ where $\sigma\beta$ is fixed-point-free of prime order $p$ for every $\beta$ in $M$. Assume also that $|A|$ and $|M|$ are coprime. Then $M=1$.

The proof goes like this,

*Proof:* Let $a\in A$ and $\beta \in M$. Then $a^{1+\sigma\beta+...+(\sigma\beta)^{p-1}}=1$ by 10.5.1. Taking the product of these equations for all $\beta$ in $M$ and remembering that $A$ is abelian, we obtain
$$1=\prod_{\beta\in M}\prod_{i=0}^{p-1}a^{(\sigma\beta)^i}=a^{|M|}\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}\prod_{\beta\in M}a^{(\sigma\beta)^i} (*)$$
We claim that if $i$ is a fixed integer satisfying $1\leq i<p-1$, the elements $(\sigma\beta)^i$, $\beta\in M$, are all different. For suppose that $(\sigma\beta)^i=(\sigma\bar{\beta})^i$; then $\sigma\beta\in\langle\sigma\bar{\beta}\rangle$ since $(i,p)=1$ and $|\sigma\beta|=p$. Thus $\sigma\beta=(\sigma\bar{\beta})^j$ where $1\leq j<p$; however this implies that $j=1$ and $\beta=\bar{\beta}$ because  $\langle \sigma\rangle\cap M=1$ and $\sigma$ has order $p$. This establishes our claim. Hence these elements $(\sigma\beta)^i$ account for all the
elements $\sigma^i\beta$, ($i$ being fixed). Therefore

$$a^{|M|}\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}\prod_{\beta\in M}a^{(\sigma\beta)^i}=a^{|M|}\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}\prod_{\beta\in M}a^{\sigma^i\beta}$$

so that $(*)$ yields

$$a^{-|M|}=\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}\prod_{\beta\in M}a^{\sigma^i\beta}$$

But the right-hand side of this last equation is clearly fixed by each element of $M$; since $(|a|,|M|)=1$, we deduce that $a$ is fixed by each such element. Because $a$ was an arbitrary element of $A$, we conclude that $M = 1$.

*My question:* He claims that $\sigma \beta=(\sigma\bar{\beta})^j$ implies $j=1$. Apparently it's because $\langle \sigma\rangle\cap M=1$ and $\sigma$ has order $p$, but I don't understand why. Can someone explain, step by step, how he gets to that conclusion?

Comment: Please do not use images to convey key information about the question. See [here for an explanation why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: The element $\sigma M$ of $G/M$ has order $p$. Then $\sigma\beta = (\sigma \bar{\beta})^j \Rightarrow (\sigma M) = (\sigma M)^j \Rightarrow j=1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for the comment. I didn't know that. From now on I will try not to use images.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh, I see. I understand now. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have typed the proof, before was an image of the proof.

Comment: Thank you for replacing the image and pledging to avoid such use in the future.